# How do I wait until all requests are finished?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How could I make the `sortOrder` function run once the `getOrders` function is fully completed?

I thought using a callback, so I expect getOrders to terminate and execute the sortOrder function, but I don´t know how to do that. What should I do, any sugestions?

```
mounted () {
    this.user = this.$q.localStorage.get.item('userInfo')
    axios.get(`${api.getOrders}${this.user.cpf}`).then(response => {
      this.orders = response.data
      if (this.orders !== '') {
        this.$q.loading.show()
        this.getOrders(callback => {
          this.sortOrder()
        })
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    getOrders: function () {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.orders.length; i++) {
        axios.get(api.obterOrderInfo(this.orders[i].orderId)).then(response => {
          this.orderInfo = this.orderInfo.concat(response.data)
        })
      }
    },
    sortOrder: function () {
      this.orderInfo.sort(this.compare)
      this.$q.loading.hide()
    },
    compare: function (x, y) {
      return x.creationDate < y.creationDate
    }
}
```

Comment: have you looked into `async`/`await` and `Promise.all`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getOrders: function () {
   // Create array of requests
   const requests = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < this.orders.length; i++) {
      requests.push(axios.get(api.obterOrderInfo(this.orders[i].orderId)))
   }

   // Map array of responses to orderInfo
   return Promise.all(requests).then(results => this.orderInfo = results.map(result => result.data))
},
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to wrap your promises together and solve them with a `Promise.all` like this:

```
getOrders: function () {
  let promises = []
  for (let i = 0; i < this.orders.length; i++) {
    const promise = axios.get(api.obterOrderInfo(this.orders[i].orderId)).then(response => {
      this.orderInfo = this.orderInfo.concat(response.data)
    })
    promises.push(promise)
  }
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
      this.sortOrder()
    })
},
```